# Android - setVisibility results in java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: android, android-layout

I am hiding a view via `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`. Later on when I try to show the view again in a different method via `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` I get the following exception

```
03-28 01:32:05.450: E/AndroidRuntime(20895): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-28 01:32:05.450: E/AndroidRuntime(20895): java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
03-28 01:32:05.450: E/AndroidRuntime(20895): at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:796)
03-28 01:32:05.450: E/AndroidRuntime(20895): at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:823)
03-28 01:32:05.450: E/AndroidRuntime(20895): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:946)
03-28 01:32:05.450: E/AndroidRuntime(20895): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:948)
03-28 01:32:05.450: E/AndroidRuntime(20895): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:948)
03-28 01:32:05.450: E/AndroidRuntime(20895): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:948)
03-28 01:32:05.450: E/AndroidRuntime(20895): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:948)
03-28 01:32:05.450: E/AndroidRuntime(20895): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:948)
03-28 01:32:05.450: E/AndroidRuntime(20895): at android.view.ViewRoot.handleDragEvent(ViewRoot.java:3027)
03-28 01:32:05.450: E/AndroidRuntime(20895): at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:2185)
03-28 01:32:05.450: E/AndroidRuntime(20895): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-28 01:32:05.450: E/AndroidRuntime(20895): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
03-28 01:32:05.450: E/AndroidRuntime(20895): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4028)
03-28 01:32:05.450: E/AndroidRuntime(20895): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 01:32:05.450: E/AndroidRuntime(20895): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491) 
03-28 01:32:05.450: E/AndroidRuntime(20895): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
03-28 01:32:05.450: E/AndroidRuntime(20895): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
03-28 01:32:05.450: E/AndroidRuntime(20895): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

When I comment out the line that changes the visibility back to visible, I don't get the exception.

I first thought that the exception would be caused by some other code iterating through a hashmap, however, I don't do any modifications while iterating through the hashmaps I use, neither do I have multithreading, which seem to be the most common reason for this exception. Also I don't get the exception when I don't change back the visibility.

**EDIT**:
The exception occurs in a custom fragment. Below is the code where I iterate over the hashmap (`mWidgetConfig`) that contains information about the configuration of custom widgets that I am trying to restore. The hashmap is a public variable in the fragment.

In an `OnDragListener` which is created by the fragment, I update the hashmap according to a certain drag operation, like this:

```
// Update the widget configuration of the fragment that created this listener
                mFragment.mWidgetConfig.put(startCircleTag, "0");
```

I also iterate over the hashmap to check a certain condition but I don't do any modification during the iteration:

```
Iterator<String> keySetItr = mFragment.mWidgetConfig.keySet().iterator();
        while(keySetItr.hasNext()) {
            String tag = keySetItr.next();
            if(mFragment.mWidgetConfig.get(tag).equals((String) destSocket.getTag())) {
                // do something, though no modification of the hashmap
                break;

            }
        }
```

In addition I do one iteration in the fragment itself while trying to restore the widget configuration. Below is the code I use to configure the widget according to the hashmap:

```
    public void configureWidgets() {
    resetWidgets();

    Iterator<String> keySetItr = mWidgetConfig.keySet().iterator();
    while(keySetItr.hasNext()) {
        String tag = keySetItr.next();
        Integer value = Integer.parseInt(mWidgetConfig.get(tag));

        ImageView destSocket = null;
        switch(value) {
        case 0:
            // The circle will not be connected to any socket
            continue;
        case 1:
            destSocket = mSocket1;
            break;
        case 2:
            destSocket = mSocket2;
            break;
        case 3:
            destSocket = mSocket3;
            break;
        }

        ImageView startCircle = (ImageView) mLayout.findViewWithTag(tag);
        ImageView startPlug = (ImageView) mLayout.findViewWithTag(tag + "_plug");

        // Replace the drawable of destSocket
        destSocket.setBackgroundDrawable(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.socket_plugged));

        // Hide plug view
        startPlug.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        // Draw a line between the start circle view and the destination socket view
        mConnectionLinesView.addLine(startCircle, destSocket);
    }
}


public void resetWidgets() {
    // Remove all lines
    mConnectionLinesView.removeLines();

    // Show all eventually previously hidden plugs
    //mPlug1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    //mPlug2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    //mPlug3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    // Set to backround drawable of the socket to the initial one
    mSocket1.setBackgroundDrawable(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.socket).mutate());
    mSocket2.setBackgroundDrawable(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.socket).mutate());
    mSocket3.setBackgroundDrawable(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.socket).mutate());
}
```

As soon as the lines that set the visibility of the "plugs" above are used in the code, I get the exception.

**SOLUTION**
The reason the exception got thrown is that I called the configuration methods in the `DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED` case statement of the `OnDragListener`. When I put the same code into the `DragEvent.ACTION_DROP` case statement the exception doesn't get thrown. No clue why. Thanks for your help guys

Comment: post your code for iterating hashmap ...and its create this exception

Comment: so how come the exception only gets thrown when I change the visiblity?

Comment: are remove or add in `while(iterator.hasNext())`

Comment: no there aren't, that's the weird thing :(

Comment: Use `ConcurrntHashMap` may be useful

Comment: Didn't work either. I also tried to put all access and modification of the `HashMap` into `synchronized(mWidgetConfig)` statements - no change here. Also (if I understand the error log correctly) the exception doesn't get thrown in one of the classes implemented by me?!

Comment: `concurrentHashmap` will help you....

Comment: It would help, but the part using the HashMap is the actual Android code ;)

Answer (score 17):

As I understand this is caused by `ViewGroup` implementation details. And it's not connected with multithreading.

When drag starts `ViewGroup` creates a HashSet of child views that must be notified about `ACTION_DRAG_ENDED` event. This is a set of visible children. When child visibility is changed a corresponding `ViewGroup` modifies that set (adding a child if its visibility is `VISIBLE`). And in your case it happens during iterations over that collection.

Think, the easiest solution for you is to postpone the visibility change.

```
view.post(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  }
});
```

And exception does not happen when you put your code into the `ACTION_DROP` case statement because that set is not being iterated at the moment you change the view visibility.

For details see [ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(DragEvent)](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/ViewGroup.java#L1100) source code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
setVisibility(View.GONE);
setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help, I still get the same exception

Comment: This then seems to be not an issue with setVisibility part.
This url may give you some hint on this issue - http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/05/avoid-concurrentmodificationexception.html

Comment: That's the thing, I'm in a single-threaded environment and I don't do any modifications during the iterations. If Android automatically threaded your app in some way, this could be the answer

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to wrap your draggable view in some `ViewGroup` (e.g. `FrameLayout`) and keep that visible all the time.

This way only the draggable view contained within will disappear leaving a hole where it was (just as before), but the parent of the wrapper won't get notified of the draggable being hidden.

Esentially go from

```
ViewGroup:parent
 ┗ View:draggable (toggling setVisible on this one, parent gets notified)
```

to

```
ViewGroup:parent
 ┗ ViewGroup:wrapper (setVisible never called on this one)
     ┗ View:draggable (toggling setVisible on this one, wrapper gets notified)
```

The `ConcurrentModificationException` is avoided here because the problematic `Map` only contains one element, hence one iteration is done, which means one call to `Iterator.hasNext`/`.next`.

*Decide for yourself if this is a hack :)*

Note: your edit has nothing to do with the question, because the exception is about `ViewGroup.mDragNotifiedChildren` and not your `Map` (see stacktrace),