# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException in View.setVisibility

Tags: android, view, drag-and-drop

I'm implementing drag'n'drop for views. When drag is started, I set visibility of the view to `INVISIBLE`, then, if the drag was interrupted - back to `VISIBLE`:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        // Skipped some code
        boolean dragStarted = v.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, v, 0);

        if (dragStarted) {
            v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
        }
    }
}
```

And:

```
if (event.getAction() == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED) {
    View droppedView = (View) event.getLocalState();
    droppedView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

And when "Drag ended" event is called, I'm getting exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(7118): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
E/AndroidRuntime(7118): java.util.ConcurrentModificationException 
E/AndroidRuntime(7118):     at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:792)
E/AndroidRuntime(7118):     at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:819) 
E/AndroidRuntime(7118):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1046)
E/AndroidRuntime(7118):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1048)
E/AndroidRuntime(7118):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1048)
E/AndroidRuntime(7118):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1048)
E/AndroidRuntime(7118):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleDragEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3471)
E/AndroidRuntime(7118):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2620)
E/AndroidRuntime(7118):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
E/AndroidRuntime(7118):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
E/AndroidRuntime(7118):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
E/AndroidRuntime(7118):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
E/AndroidRuntime(7118):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(7118):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
E/AndroidRuntime(7118):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
E/AndroidRuntime(7118):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeMethod)
```

Why and how to fix it?

Comment: just an idea , but have you tried the API demos ? they have a nice drag&drop example there. just play with it and change the visibility exactly when you wish to. since i don't have a device with API11+ , i cannot check if whatever i do helps (the emulator is not enough as it sometimes gives false results)

Comment: about why, this exception occurs when you're inserting or deleting some element of an iterable, when you're iterating on that. but it seems to bee a bug in android.

Comment: try `droppedView.post(new Runnable() {public void run() {droppedView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}});` you will need to make droppedView final

Comment: I've written some explanations why the exception happens http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899382/android-setvisibility-results-in-java-util-concurrentmodificationexception/11667687#11667687

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can try this

```
if (event.getAction() == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED) {
    final View droppedView = (View) event.getLocalState();
    droppedView.post(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            droppedView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
```

Looks like Android itself trying to access View state at the same time as you end dragging.

**EDIT**

More precise explanation. By setting `setVisibility()`, you're including or excluding `View` from Android internal collection of views, that should respond to drag events. This collection is used during dispatch of drag events, and therefore by trying to `setVisibility` (in other words, trying to modify listeners of drag events) you're causing `ConcurrentModificationException`

Answer (score 0):

The best way is :

```
    view.post(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  }
});
```

if we use:

```
 if (event.getAction() == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED) {
    final View droppedView = (View) event.getLocalState();
    droppedView.post(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            droppedView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
```

you will still get force close Null.pointer. ...

Answer (score -1):

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899382/android-setvisibility-results-in-java-util-concurrentmodificationexception) can help. here in the given link says: instead of `DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED` use `DragEvent.ACTION_DROP`.

Comment: I need to process the cancellation of the drag'n'drop, when the view is not dropped.