# Android drag action drag_ended, errors

Tags: android

```
04-03 02:12:01.880 16450-16450/? E/SettingsReceiverActivity: PREF_DONT_ASK_AGAIN : true
04-03 02:12:13.832 17268-17268/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
04-03 02:12:13.832 17268-17268/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
04-03 02:12:14.232 591-708/? E/PackageManager: parse pkg : /data/app/vmdl388123438.tmp
04-03 02:12:14.232 591-17303/? E/PackageManager: dexopt start
04-03 02:12:15.864 591-17303/? E/PackageManager: dexopt end
04-03 02:12:19.097 4478-4478/? E/SamsungIME: mOCRHelper is null
04-03 02:12:19.107 4478-4478/? E/SamsungIME: mOCRHelper is null
04-03 02:12:20.819 157-397/? E/cutils: Failed to mkdirat(/storage/extSdCard/Android): Read-only file system
04-03 02:12:20.949 157-397/? E/cutils: Failed to mkdirat(/storage/extSdCard/Android): Read-only file system
04-03 02:12:21.049 157-397/? E/cutils: Failed to mkdirat(/storage/extSdCard/Android): Read-only file system
04-03 02:12:21.339 591-601/? A/ActivityManager: Service ServiceRecord{431b3d48 u0 com.google.android.apps.maps/com.google.android.apps.gmm.prefetch.PrefetcherService} in process ProcessRecord{43123078 16783:com.google.android.apps.maps/u0a60} not same as in map: null
04-03 02:12:21.659 17369-17369/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
04-03 02:12:21.659 17369-17369/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
04-03 02:12:22.620 4478-4478/? E/SamsungIME:          isHWKeyboardConnected() = false --> false
04-03 02:12:22.811 591-591/? E/Tethering: No numeric data
04-03 02:12:23.341 17435-17435/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.Notification$Action$Builder', referenced from method b.a
04-03 02:12:23.411 17435-17435/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method b.a
04-03 02:12:23.521 17435-17435/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.Notification$Action$Builder', referenced from method b.a
04-03 02:12:23.571 17435-17435/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'bg', referenced from method b.a
04-03 02:12:23.571 17435-17435/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'bi', referenced from method b.a
04-03 02:12:23.601 17435-17435/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.RemoteInput[]', referenced from method b.a
04-03 02:12:25.283 976-976/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver: Invalid parameter app
04-03 02:12:25.283 976-976/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver: Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
04-03 02:12:28.806 17563-17621/? E/fb4a(:dash):AppStateReporter: Error acquiring lock: /data/data/com.facebook.katana/app_state_logs/55aad98f-9bd2-46e5-90eb-55f53313613f.txt
                                                                 java.io.IOException: fcntl failed: EAGAIN (Try again)
                                                                     at java.nio.FileChannelImpl.basicLock(FileChannelImpl.java:123)
                                                                     at java.nio.FileChannelImpl.tryLock(FileChannelImpl.java:177)
                                                                     at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.tryLock(FileChannel.java:587)
                                                                     at com.facebook.analytics.reporters.AppStateReporter.a(AppStateReporter.java:141)
                                                                     at com.facebook.analytics.reporters.AppStateReporter.c(AppStateReporter.java:94)
                                                                     at com.facebook.analytics.reporters.AppStateReporter.a(AppStateReporter.java:55)
                                                                     at com.facebook.common.noncriticalinit.NonCriticalInitializer.a(NonCriticalInitializer.java:103)
                                                                     at com.facebook.common.noncriticalinit.NonCriticalInitializer$2.run(NonCriticalInitializer.java:116)
                                                                     at com.facebook.common.appchoreographer.DefaultAppChoreographer$5.run(DefaultAppChoreographer.java:384)
                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
                                                                     at com.facebook.common.executors.WrappingExecutorService$1.run(WrappingExecutorService.java:77)
                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                     at com.facebook.common.executors.DefaultConstrainedListeningExecutorService$Worker.run(DefaultConstrainedListeningExecutorService.java:327)
                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                     at com.facebook.common.executors.NamedThreadFactory$1.run(NamedThreadFactory.java:42)
                                                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
                                                                  Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: fcntl failed: EAGAIN (Try again)
                                                                     at libcore.io.Posix.fcntlFlock(Native Method)
                                                                     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.fcntlFlock(ForwardingOs.java:54)
                                                                     at java.nio.FileChannelImpl.basicLock(FileChannelImpl.java:121)
                                                                     at java.nio.FileChannelImpl.tryLock(FileChannelImpl.java:177) 
                                                                     at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.tryLock(FileChannel.java:587) 
                                                                     at com.facebook.analytics.reporters.AppStateReporter.a(AppStateReporter.java:141) 
                                                                     at com.facebook.analytics.reporters.AppStateReporter.c(AppStateReporter.java:94) 
                                                                     at com.facebook.analytics.reporters.AppStateReporter.a(AppStateReporter.java:55) 
                                                                     at com.facebook.common.noncriticalinit.NonCriticalInitializer.a(NonCriticalInitializer.java:103) 
                                                                     at com.facebook.common.noncriticalinit.NonCriticalInitializer$2.run(NonCriticalInitializer.java:116) 
                                                                     at com.facebook.common.appchoreographer.DefaultAppChoreographer$5.run(DefaultAppChoreographer.java:384) 
                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422) 
                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422) 
                                                                     at com.facebook.common.executors.WrappingExecutorService$1.run(WrappingExecutorService.java:77) 
                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422) 
                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
                                                                     at com.facebook.common.executors.DefaultConstrainedListeningExecutorService$Worker.run(DefaultConstrainedListeningExecutorService.java:327) 
                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                                                                     at com.facebook.common.executors.NamedThreadFactory$1.run(NamedThreadFactory.java:42) 
                                                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841) 
04-03 02:12:29.057 157-397/? E/cutils: Failed to mkdirat(/storage/extSdCard/Android): Read-only file system
04-03 02:12:29.067 157-397/? E/cutils: Failed to mkdirat(/storage/extSdCard/Android): Read-only file system
04-03 02:12:31.329 591-856/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 3567
04-03 02:12:34.502 157-397/? E/cutils: Failed to mkdirat(/storage/extSdCard/Android): Read-only file system
04-03 02:12:34.522 157-397/? E/cutils: Failed to mkdirat(/storage/extSdCard/Android): Read-only file system
04-03 02:12:34.532 157-397/? E/cutils: Failed to mkdirat(/storage/extSdCard/Android): Read-only file system
04-03 02:12:34.532 157-397/? E/cutils: Failed to mkdirat(/storage/extSdCard/Android): Read-only file system
04-03 02:12:35.383 976-976/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver: Invalid parameter app
04-03 02:12:35.383 976-976/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver: Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
04-03 02:12:46.694 17421-17421/com.example.caneraydin.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                      Process: com.example.caneraydin.myapplication, PID: 17421
                                                                                      java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
                                                                                          at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:806)
                                                                                          at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:833)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1191)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1193)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1193)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1193)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleDragEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5250)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.access$900(ViewRootImpl.java:115)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3462)
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
                                                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-03 02:12:47.164 591-17912/? E/android.os.Debug: !@Dumpstate > sdumpstate -k -t -z -d -m 17421 -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
04-03 02:12:47.365 4478-4478/? E/SamsungIME:          isHWKeyboardConnected() = false --> false
04-03 02:12:48.225 591-591/? E/Tethering: No numeric data
04-03 02:12:54.391 591-731/? E/ConnectivityService: net.tcp.usercfg.default not found in system default properties
04-03 02:12:54.391 591-731/? E/ConnectivityService: Can't set delayed ACK size:java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sys/kernel/ipv4/tcp_use_userconfig: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
04-03 02:12:54.391 591-731/? E/ConnectivityService: net.tcp.delack.default not found in system default properties
04-03 02:12:54.391 591-731/? E/ConnectivityService: Can't set delayed ACK size:java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sys/kernel/ipv4/tcp_delack_seg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
04-03 02:12:54.472 591-731/? E/ConnectivityService: Exception trying to remove a route: java.lang.IllegalStateException: command '2337 interface route remove wlan0 default 192.168.0.0 24 0.0.0.0' failed with '400 2337 Failed to remove route from default table (No such process)'
04-03 02:12:54.492 591-731/? E/ConnectivityService: Exception trying to remove a route: java.lang.IllegalStateException: command '2338 interface route remove wlan0 default 192.168.0.1 32 0.0.0.0' failed with '400 2338 Failed to remove route from default table (No such process)'
04-03 02:12:54.502 591-731/? E/ConnectivityService: Exception trying to remove a route: java.lang.IllegalStateException: command '2339 interface route remove wlan0 default 0.0.0.0 0 192.168.0.1' failed with '400 2339 Failed to remove route from default table (No such process)'
04-03 02:12:55.152 591-700/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for telephony
04-03 02:12:55.262 976-17261/? E/GCM: Wifi connection closed with errorCode 20
04-03 02:12:58.636 18032-18032/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.speech.tts.Voice', referenced from method com.google.android.tts.service.GoogleTTSService.onGetVoices
04-03 02:13:01.328 591-856/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 3568
04-03 02:13:22.219 591-699/? E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
04-03 02:13:22.259 591-717/? E/InputDispatcher: channel ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
04-03 02:13:31.327 591-856/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 3569
04-03 02:14:01.337 591-856/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 3570
04-03 02:14:31.336 591-856/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 3571
```

Those are errors

these are my codes
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36373171/android-drag-drop-imaview-onto-other-imageview

I dropped image on to empty place but it gave errors. when i drop on to another image,again errors.

What is wrong? I cant solve for days.

Answer (score 0):

Refering to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11106365/1843141), you may try that:

```
case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
    final View droppedView = (View) event.getLocalState();
    ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) droppedView.getParent();
    owner.post(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            owner.removeView(droppedView);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: but i did not try to drop on to other image when i got those errors. if i dont drop on to othe rimage, it doesnot go to actiondrop. i just dropped on to empty place.