# RxJava Android caused ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I'm a new in RxJava in Android development. I had changed in project AsyncTask to RxJava and got a ConcurrentModificationException. Yes, I used collection (sparseArray) but it doesn't matter 'cause exeption was thrown in findViewById.setVisibility. Only when I try to invoke setVisibility. I confused, what I do wrong? I have a TextView in fragment. At first I set up OnClickListener, in listener I init Single.fromCallable, then I set up OnDragListener

```
TextView tv;

tv.setOnClickListener(v -> {
          if (isClickEnable) {
              tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cheap_dark);
              cheapInObservable(tv);

          }

});

tv.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());

private void cheapInObservable(TextView tView) {
        Single.fromCallable( () ->  tView).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
              .delay(250, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
              .doOnSuccess(this::onSuccessCheapIn)
              .subscribe();
    }
```

And in this code I get exeption:

```
private class MyDragListener implements View.OnDragListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            View dragView = (View)event.getLocalState();
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                    if(!event.getResult()) {
                        if(dragView == v) {
                            dragView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            activity.findViewById(sparseCheaps.get(dragView.getId())).
                                     setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        }
                    }
                    break;


private void onSuccessCheapIn(TextView tv) {
            tv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            TextView tvd = activity.findViewById(sparseCheaps.get(tv.getId()));
            tvd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
            tvd.animate().rotation(0);
            int up = activity.findViewById(R.id.guidelineGlowUp).getTop();
            int left = getXcoord(tvd);
            set.setDuration(400).playTogether(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(tvd, TextView.TRANSLATION_X,
                    tvd.getX(), left),
                    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(tvd, TextView.TRANSLATION_Y, tvd.getY(), up - 3));

            set.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator((float) 0.4));

            set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    isAnimationCheaps = false;
                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                }
            });

            set.start();
        }
```

I've found out that only the exeption is thrown when I use setVisibility. If I use AsyncTask instead of Rx it works without exception

StackTrace is:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:795)
        at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:822)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1154)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1156)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1156)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1156)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1156)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1156)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1156)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1156)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleDragEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4322)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.access$1100(ViewRootImpl.java:103)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3407)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5370)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post your exception stack trace

Comment: It looks like `TextView` emits a series of events, all of which will occur on a `Schedulers.io()` thread. Since `DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED` is a GUI-oriented event, it should be handled on the `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()` thread. That's the rule in Android (or any environment with a GUI management).

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: @BobDalgleish he's specifying AndroidSchedulers.mainThread() in delay(...), so subscribeOn(Schedulers.io() doesn't matter here.

Comment: post your onSuccessCheapIn code

Comment: The base idea is :there are some TextViews on the screen. TextViews can be moved to another position on the screen in two ways.  First way is press on it (onClickListener) with delay 250ms. Second way - drag&drop.  I drag TextView to the another position and release it and in this moment exception is thrown. It's very strange that AsyncTask works well instead of Single.Callable. And this exception is thrown only in DRAG_ENDED event only during setVisibility method. I don't use Map and Iterators. I've change sparseArray to simple int[] array but exception remains

Comment: @Dimezis, I've added onSuccessCheapIn code

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with threading or RxJava, it's crashing in ViewGroup's code, and there are already same issues on SOF - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988671/java-util-concurrentmodificationexception-in-view-setvisibility

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.util.ConcurrentModificationException in View.setVisibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988671/java-util-concurrentmodificationexception-in-view-setvisibility)

Comment: @Dimezis, great thanks, it's the same situation, I've moved setVisibility() to post() like this : tView.post(() -> tView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)) and now it works fine. Indeed, changing setVisibility() causes the including or excluding View from Android internal collection of views